# How to select a file using swing and pass that file to a method as string?

Tags: java, swing, file

I have a swing code. In which I will select a file and I want to pass that file to a method as a string. how to do it? Please give me a simple solution.This code should be in java

Ok I got the answer just follow this answer

[Reading a txt file in a Java GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667041/reading-a-txt-file-in-a-java) gui/13667222#13667222

Comment: What did you try? Just open your favorite search engine and enter 'java swing file chooser example'...

Comment: *"Please give me a simple solution"*  Please give me a pony ..and an ice-cream.  (AKA - SO is not a code factory.)

Comment: @Mad  Are you ..mad?  Last time I tried to eat ice-cream while riding a pony in a chopper, it *all came to tears.*  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Compromise, a Pegasus and ice-cream ;)

Comment: @Mad Now that *would* be cool.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, do you want the name of the file or the whole path...

[`File#getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29) will return just the name of the file, without the path where as [`File#getPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getPath%28%29) will return the path and name

Ten seconds reading the API docs would have given you the answer ;)

Comment: I suspect the OP actually wants the file **content** as the `String`, but until they clarify, it's anybody's guess.

Answer (score 7):

please read about [File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html). They're easy to use and reuse.

Comment: Yeah I know file choosers but how to pass that selected file to a method as string? will toString() helps?

Comment: *"will toString() helps?"*  What happened when ***you tried it?***

Comment: you get File object from JFileChooser.getSelectedFile(). Please read the documentation. We can get the file-name as a String from the File object. READ the documentation