# Reading a txt file in a Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, file-io, jtextcomponent

All I want to do is display the entire contents of a txt file. How would I go about doing this? I'm assuming that I will set the text of a JLabel to be a string that contains the entire file, but how do I get the entire file into a string? Also, does the txt file go in the src folder in Eclipse?

Answer (score 4):

This code to display the selected file contents in you Jtext area

```
      static void readin(String fn, JTextComponent pane) 
              {
             try 
              {
               FileReader fr = new FileReader(fn);
               pane.read(fr, null);
               fr.close();
              }
                 catch (IOException e) 
                 {
                  System.err.println(e);
                 }
              }
```

To choose the file

```
         String cwd = System.getProperty("user.dir");
         final JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(cwd);

            JButton filebutton = new JButton("Choose");
            filebutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
            {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                if (jfc.showOpenDialog(frame) !=JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)

                        return;
                  File f = jfc.getSelectedFile();



            readin(f.toString(), textpane);

                  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        frame.setCursor(Cursor.
                            getPredefinedCursor(
                            Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: The `fr.close()` statement should be in a finally block. And how is that part which sets the cursor of the frame relevant to the question ?

Comment: @Robin as this question related to getting the file name it is right and my answer is right.

Comment: @Murali Robins suggestions isn't about discusion about whatever

Answer (score 3):

> All I want to do is display the entire contents of a txt file. How
>   would I go about doing this? I'm assuming that I will set the text of
>   a JLabel to be a string that contains the entire file but how do I get the entire file into a string?

You would be better of using a [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) to do this. You can also look at the [read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29) method.

> does the txt file go in the src folder in Eclipse?

Nope. You can read files from any where. The tutorial on ["Reading, Writing, and Creating Files"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) would be a good place to start

Answer (score 2):

- create text file in your project's working folder
- read your text file line by line
- store the line contents in `stringBuilder` variable
- then append next line contents to `stringBuilder` variable
- then assign the content of your `StringBuilder` variable to the `JLabel`'s text property

But it is not good idea to store whole file's data into `JLabel`, use `JTextArea` or any other text containers.

Read your file like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
       line = br.readLine();
    }
    String everything = sb.toString();
} finally {
    br.close();
}
```

now assign value of everything to `JLabel` or `JTextArea`

```
JLabel1.text=everything;
```

Comment: And how will the "\n" help in case of a `JLabel` ? And I wasn't aware that `JLabel` had a protected `text` field (and it seems the javadoc isn't aware of this either)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `java.io` to open a file stream.
2. Read content from file by lines or bytes.
3. Append content to `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`
4. Set `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` to `JLable.text`.

But I recommend using `JTextArea`..

You don't need to put this file in src folder.